# java.sql.SQLException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'org.postgresql.Driver

Tags: java, postgresql, apache, tomcat, jdbc

Tengo el siguiente error en tomcat 9.0.83 al iniciarlo en mi eclipse en java 8 funciona bien y levanta el proyecto pero quiero levantarlo en java 9 cambiando el java compilador de java 8 a 9 y me marca esto en consola

*aclaro que quiero hacer la migracion de un proyecto de java 7 a java 9. Es la primera vez que hago esto cualquier ayuda o sugerencia me ayudaria mucho.. :)

> nov 17, 2023 10:45:33 A. M. org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener addResource
> ADVERTENCIA: No pude registrar en JMX: [javax.naming.NamingException: Excepción inesperada resolviendo referencia [Root exception is java.sql.SQLException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'org.postgresql.Driver']]
> nov 17, 2023 10:45:33 A. M. org.apache.naming.NamingContext lookup
> ADVERTENCIA: Excepción inesperada resolviendo referencia
> java.sql.SQLException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'org.postgresql.Driver'
> at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DriverFactory.createDriver(DriverFactory.java:53)
> at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:465)
> at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:529)
> at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getLogWriter(BasicDataSource.java:1036)
> at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory.createDataSource(BasicDataSourceFactory.java:311)
> at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance(BasicDataSourceFactory.java:406)
> at org.apache.naming.factory.FactoryBase.getObjectInstance(FactoryBase.java:96)
> at java.naming/javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:342)
> at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:864)
> at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:158)
> at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:850)
> at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:172)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.addResource(NamingContextListener.java:986)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.createNamingContext(NamingContextListener.java:536)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.lifecycleEvent(NamingContextListener.java:243)
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:114)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4820)
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:683)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:658)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:661)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1184)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1932)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:123)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:1094)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:476)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1617)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:318)
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:114)
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:402)
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:345)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:893)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:794)
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:866)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:248)
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:433)
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:921)
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:347)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:478)
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver
> at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1329)
> at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1141)
> at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DriverFactory.createDriver(DriverFactory.java:48)
> ... 55 more

Ya intente cambiando el tomcat a 11 y lo mismo e intente cambiar el context en el tomcat y me marca error al iniciar el niño en consola y en mi context lo tengo asi..